# How to call scalar function in QueryOver statement

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hql, queryover

I've a scalar function in `SQL Server` I want to use it in QueryOver in HQL.

Please translate the give SQL to HQL.

```
Select ID,Name,dbo.GetStatus(ID) From SST_Request
```

or any other way to call UDF in sub query of HQL statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481737/scalar-valued-function-in-nhibernate

Comment: And a bit to wide: there is many querying API with NHibernate. The answer would not be same depending on the querying API you wish to use. See [here](/q/37259653/1178314) by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fluent hibernate  have build in option to map SQL server user defined function.

> Map(o => o.Status).Formula("dbo.GetStatus('ID)").ReadOnly();